# LINQ AssociateWith for data context generating LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN

Tags: linq-to-sql

I'm trying to create an "AssociateWith" data load option for my context to filter rows that the current user has access to. My simple data model is as such:

**Tables**
UserPermissions
PK: ID
FK: RelatedUserID nullable
FK: RelatedItemID not nullable

Users
PK: ID

Items
PK: ID
FK: RelatedCategoryID not nullable

Categories
PK: ID

On my datacontext, I'm trying to do something like:

```
//dbContext is my LINQ context 
//current_user_id is the id of my current logged in user 
var dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
//issue->UsersPermissions is one->many relationship
// if I omit this LoadWith line, no associatewith filter
// is created in the generated sql code
dlo.LoadWith<Items>(i=>i.UserPermissions); 

dlo.AssociateWith<Items>(i=>
i.UserPermissions.Where(p=>
p.RelatedUserID.HasValue && p.RelatedUserID.Value == current_users_id));
dbContext.LoadOptions = dlo;
```

Everything seems reasonable to me, but the query generated in SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t1].[ID] AS [ID2], [t1].[RelatedUserID], [t1].[RelatedItemID] 
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [dbo].[UserPermissions] AS [t2]
WHERE (([t2].[RelatedUserID] = @p0)) AND ([t2].[RelatedItemID] = [t0].[ID])
) AS [value]
FROM [dbo].[Items] AS [t0]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[UserPermissions] AS [t1] ON ([t1].[RelatedUserID] = @p0) 
AND     
([t1].[RelatedItemID] = [t0].[ID])
ORDER BY [t0].[ID], [t1].[ID]
```

How can I force an INNER JOIN instead of the LEFT OUTER JOIN? Am I modeling my relationship incorrectly on the backend?

Thanks for any help.

MMAS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LINQ to SQL generates the LEFT OUTER JOIN simply because `UserPermissions.RelatedUserID` column is nullable. The underlying LINQ provider just isn't 'smart' enough to further optimize that query to a simple INNER JOIN. I don't think there is anything you can do about this.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of -  

in case you're curious, the reason it is nullable is because the table will eventually reference another FK (lets call it RelatedUsersCompanyID) which is also nullable and in practice either the RelatedUserID or RelatedUsersCompanyID will always be provided. The idea is that instead of adding a row to the user table for each user who has access to an item, then we can add a row that allows any user in particular company access to that same item. 

Any bright ideas as to how I can get the behavior I want with the AssociateWith method for such a data model? :)

Comment: Can't you spit the `UserPermissions` table in a table for users and a table for companies? You should normally try to minimize the amount of nullable columns in your database. Besides, why are you using `Associatewith` to build the filter? Is there any reason to not just do the filtering the 'usual' way (in LINQ queries)?

Comment: I was hoping to make it easier on the developers by building the filter into the datacontext since we will almost always be filtering on permissions. Unfortunately, and I'm not sure why, even if I make my RelatedItemID on the permissions table required, I still get a LEFT OUTER JOIN generated. No clue why in that case...

Comment: Why is this LEFT OUTER a problem for you? Using the `AssociateWith` seems to be an interesting approach I never though of before. I'm not sure you can do all the filtering you need. I often write extension methods for this. For instance: `GetForUser(this IQueryable<UserPermissions> p, int userId)`. This allows you to write `db.UserPermissions.GetForUser(id)`. Still, your approach is an interesting one.

Comment: The left outer join ended up returning all rows with NULL in the columns of the rows who weren't able to be joined. An inner join would have eliminated those rows, which was what I was hoping for...